# Session variable not updating when going to a specific route

Tags: javascript, session, meteor, routes, iron-router

I'm doing something wrong while setting Session variables and handling the Router

main.js:

```
Template.global.onCreated(function(){
    Session.setDefault("musicFilteredCategory", "latest")
});
```

router.js:

```
Router.route("/music/:category?", {
    name: "music",
    template: "music",
    beforeAction: function () {
        var category = this.params.category;
        Session.set("musicFilteredCategory", category);
    }
});
```

but when I open page "/music/latin-radio" and I check `Session.get("musicFilteredCategory")` I get "latest" instead of "latin-radio"

later I changed Session.setDefault("musicFilteredCategory", "latest") to outside the `Template.global.onCreated({})` and the result is still the same.

What should be the best practice to do this?

I also want to add this feature once this is fixed:
when the user goes to "/music" to be redirected to "/music/:defaultMusicCategory"

**PS: I'm using Meteor 1.2.0.1 & Iron Router 1.0.9**

Comment: Isn't it [`onBeforeAction` rather than `beforeAction`](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#using-hooks)?

Comment: in the console. this is only happening to me on page load.
I believe my helpers are ok because I've managed a way to workaround this with a click event that sets new variable and loads the category as it should, but this is not working when I open the page directly n a category

Comment: thanks @Kyll that solved most of the problem. it now works when I open any url like "/music/:category" but if I open simply "/music" it's not grabbing the default `musicFilteredCategory`

Comment: If you call "/music" `this.params.category` is undefined. Check this and, if true, redirect to your wanted route.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kyll pointed out I should use onBeforeAction for the function to run.

This solved part of my problem, but the categories were not being changed when accessing the different routes.

Here's what I had to do:

```
Router.route("/music/:category?", {
    name: "music",
    template: "music",
    onBeforeAction: function () {
        var category = this.params.category;
        if (category !== "undefined") {
            Session.set("musicFilteredCategory", category);
        }
        this.render("music");
    }
});
```

This doesn't cover the route "/music" (without the slash) so I also had to add this route, I placed it before the code above

```
Router.route("/music", {
    name: "music",
    template: "music"
});
```

To resolve this I had to move the `Session.setDefault()` outside the templates scope as they were overriding the Session established on the router, so I had to put them inside a `Meteor.startup` function

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    Session.setDefault("musicFilteredCategory", "latest");
});
```